# Android - Play a Youtube video

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-videoview

What is the best way to play a Youtube Video in my Android app ? I want to play the video in my app, and not in youtube's app. 
I make some search with the VideoView, but it seems that it's obsolete now...
Have you some examples ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use android webview and embed a youtube video inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Youtube Api Demo App](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications), it shows how to use the `Youtube Player API` and the different ways to reproduce videos (using a `YouTubePlayerView`, using `YoutubePlayerFragment`, etc). However, it only shows how to display a video when you already know the `id` of the video.

If you want to search for a video and then display it. Then you need to learn how to use the [Youtube Data Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). [Here is an example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252C%20snippet&maxResults=1&q=moon&type=video&_h=2&) of a request which returns a JSON response (just click "execute").

To use the Data Api from Android, you can use an `HttpURLConnection` object, or use the [Youtube Data Api Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3), that's up to you.

Once you have retrieved the video's data from the `Youtube Data Api`. Use the `Youtube Player Api` to display the videos.